# How to add double finger tap in my android application?

Tags: android, gesture, gesturedetector

I want to implement two finger tap in my application. I have tried so many example as well as android developer guide. 
[Here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch) is a sample

But when i implemented this in my code it is showing error. I have tried to implements other Listener
`GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`, `GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener`
But their corresponding method are not providing enough method to implement Double finger tap or may be i could not use those method.
Now what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this class from this library

> TwoFingerGestureDetector (abstract)

Abstract class that extends the BaseGestureDetector and that every new gesture detector class for two finger operations should extend.

https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

Comment: Thank you @Survivor. I saw this library. But i am wondering is this work only for double finger tap. Not double finger gesture.